# Why empty spacing is showing when i hide a DIV

Tags: html

I am having 2 div's as follows based on checking i will show corresponding `DIV` but when i am showing 2nd div the empty space that was occupied by first div is showing an empty space and the 2nd div is showing in its place. This is how i write

Style Sheet

```
<style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 268px;
            height: 19px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            left: 335px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style2
        {
            width: 502px;
            height: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 51px;
            left: 226px;
            z-index: 1;
             float:left;
        }
        .style3
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 68px;
            left: 773px;
            float: right;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #c0c0c0;
            height: auto;
            width: 162px;
        }
        .add_emp_bor
        {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px dotted #000;
            background-color: #c0c0c0;
        }
        .add_emp_bor1
        {
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px dotted #000;
        }
        .center
        {
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #c0c0c0;
        }
        .style4
        {
            width: 83px;
            height: 19px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 96px;
            left: 353px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .ddlcenter
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style5
        {
            width: 933px;
            height: 40px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 244px;
            left: 9px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style6
        {
            width: 164px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 325px;
            left: 23px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style7
        {
            width: 164px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 325px;
            left: 221px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style8
        {
            width: 164px;
            height: 21px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 325px;
            left: 426px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style9
        {
            width: 164px;
            height: 21px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 324px;
            left: 622px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style10
        {
            width: 164px;
            height: 21px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 324px;
            left: 812px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style11
        {
            width: 995px;
            height: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 340px;
            left: 11px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style12
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 373px;
            left: 13px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style13
        {
            width: 357px;
            height: 27px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 17px;
            left: 654px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style14
        {
            width: 629px;
            height: 27px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 52px;
            left: 16px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style15
        {
            width: 634px;
            height: 27px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 93px;
            left: 15px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style16
        {
            width: 312px;
            height: 52px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 60px;
            left: 676px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style17
        {
            width: 65px;
            height: 19px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 117px;
            left: 786px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style18
        {
            width: 998px;
            height: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 125px;
            left: 2px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style19
        {
            width: 89px;
            height: 77px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 37px;
            left: 12px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style20
        {
            width: 137px;
            height: 39px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 532px;
            left: 11px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style21
        {
            width: 96px;
            height: 77px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 37px;
            float:left;
            left: 135px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style22
        {
            width: 96px;
            height: 77px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 38px;
            left: 270px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style23
        {
            width: 96px;
            height: 76px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 39px;
            left: 403px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style24
        {
            width: 96px;
            height: 77px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 36px;
            left: 547px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style25
        {
            width: 306px;
            height: 72px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 48px;
            left: 677px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style26
        {
            width: 137px;
            height: 39px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 686px;
            left: 11px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style27
        {
            width: 8px;
            height: 43px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 56px;
            left: 532px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style28
        {
            width: 137px;
            height: 52px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 33px;
            float:left;
            left: 103px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style29
        {
            width: 95px;
            height: 52px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 32px;
            float:left;
            left: 0px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style30
        {
            width: 8px;
            height: 43px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 36px;
            left: 223px;
            float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style31
        {
            width: 412px;
            height: 27px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 0px;
            float:left;
        }
        .style32
        {
            width: 412px;
            height: 27px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 16px;
            left: 245px;
             float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style33
        {
            width: 306px;
            height: 72px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 29px;
             float:left;
            left: 677px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style34
        {
            width: 65px;
            height: 19px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 91px;
            left: 786px;
             float:left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .style35
        {
            width: 998px;
            height: 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 2px;
            float: left;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>


<div id="divStarr" runat="server" class="style12" visible="false">
            <div style="float: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; font-weight: bold;">
                STAAR
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="style13">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstStaar" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="357px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Accomodated"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Modified"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Alternate"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style14">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkEnglish" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Reading English&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Math English&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Science English&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Social Studies English&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Writing English&nbsp;"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style15">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSpanish" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Reading Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Math Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Science Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Social Studies Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Writing Spanish"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style16">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" CssClass="add_emp_bor1" runat="server" Height="52px"
                Width="306px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;" class="style17">
            Comments
        </div>
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" class="style18">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divCourse" runat="server" class="style20" visible="false">
        <div style="float: left; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; font-weight: bold;">
            End of Course Exam
        </div>
        <div class="style19">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCourse" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="96px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="English I"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="English II"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="English III"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style21">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCourse1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="105px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Algebra I"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Geometry"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Algebra II"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style22">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCourse2" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="101px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Biology"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Chemistry"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Physics"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style23">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCourse3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="146px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="World Geography"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="World History"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="U.S. History"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div style="border-right: 1px solid #808080;" class="style27">
        </div>
        <div class="style24">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chklstCourse4" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="125px">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Accommodated"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Modified"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Alternate"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </div>
        <div class="style25">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments1" CssClass="add_emp_bor1" runat="server" Height="52px"
                Width="306px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;" class="style17">
            Comments
        </div>
        <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" class="style18">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sample image

[image]

My code to visible a div

```
protected void chkTaks_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkTaks.Checked)
        {
            divTAKS.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            divTAKS.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you hiding the `div`? If you're using `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`, your non-visible `div` will still occupy space.

Comment: I'm trying not to sound rude, but really, go read up on CSS and HTML. Use the flow of elements, don't fight it. And for the love of your favourite deity, use more descriptive class names than `"style1"`, `"style2"`, ..., `"style35"`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `display:none;` to hide the div? To show the div again, you can use `display:block;`. Just doing `visibility:hidden` will keep the space that the div takes up.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden` in order to remove the element and not take up space, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a div hidden with `visibility:hidden` it only hides the element but the browser still reserves a place on the page. However if you use `display: none` then element will not be visible on the page and no space will be reserved.

Comment: But i am hiding them using `c#` code in that case how can i make visible using `Display`

Answer (score -1):

your positions are absolutes, if you use relative positions and don't specify the top property, you should get the expected result.

Comment: Then i can not place my div's in the exact place i need

Comment: yes, you can. But you would need to learn proper CSS of course. What you're doing right now has more to do with Photoshop than web development.